# How to use INSERT INTO SELECT

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEES (
    EMPLOYEEID INT NOT NULL,
    DEPARTMENTID INT NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE MANAGERS (
    EMPLOYEEID INT NOT NULL,
    DEPARTMENTID INT NOT NULL,
    ALTER_TIMESTAMP TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
);
```

I want to insert EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEEID, EMPLOYEES.DEPARTMENTID, ALTER_TIMESTAMP to MANAGERS table  using INSERT INTO SELECT. (ALTER_TIMESTAMP col is current time)

I want this result
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUNGC.png)

this is my code

```
INSERT INTO MANAGERS
(EMPLOYEEID, DEPARTMENTID, ALTER_TIMESTAMP)
SELECT EMPLOYEEID, DEPARTMENTID, to_char(ALTER_TIMESTAMP, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS:FF3')
FROM EMPLOYEES, DUAL;
```

but "ORA-00904: "DUAL"."ALTER_TIMESTAMP": invalid identifier"

Comment: When you use an expression remember to alias it, whether you are creating a view, using an inline view, or in the Insert statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have no column named "alter_timestamp" in your table, this is the cause of the error message.

Try the next insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO MANAGERS
(EMPLOYEEID, DEPARTMENTID, ALTER_TIMESTAMP)
SELECT EMPLOYEEID, DEPARTMENTID, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
FROM EMPLOYEES;
```